# How to set a state between sending a request and receiving the data with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i'm trying to get so information from a php function that i call in ajax so i want to do a state between the sending data and receiving them

```
$.ajax({
         //Some code

        })
    // putting a state between the two 
        .done(function( json ) {

          //Some code

        });
```

Thanks

Comment: Like some sort of waiting?

Comment: Define "state". Better yet, step back and describe what you want to achieve by setting one.

Comment: Set a loader when you create the call and hide it in the `.done`(callback)

Answer (score 0):

The @Daan answer is not correct at all because AJAX is asynchronous by default, then you are not sure if .ajaxStop will execute after the ajax call ends. @GuyT comment I think is a good point.

I have two variants:

The first one: execute the `startWait()` just before the ajax is called and `stopWait()` inside the `.done()` and `.fail()` statements. Look:

```
startWait();
$.ajax({
    //setup the ajax call
})
.done(function(res){
    //do some code
    stopWait();
})
.fail(function(res){
    //do some code
    stopWait()
});
```

The second one is execute `startWait()` and `stopWait()` inside the `.done()`:

```
$.ajax({
    //setup the ajax call
})
.done(function(res){
    startWait();
    //do some code
    stopWait();
});
```

If you ask me, I prefer the first one, because I make sure to show a loader (or run code) while the ajax is run and I stop it when all is finished even if it falls.

For your question, the first one is the better choice too.

Answer (score -2):

As you said in the comments you want some sort of waiting time use ajaxStart and ajaxStop.

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
   //ajax start create a loader or something
});


$.ajax({

}).done(function(data) {

});

$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
    //stop the loader
});
```

Comment: i guess that is influenced by the original post